# Make a field in fieldset of ModelAdmin required in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I need to make some fields in the fieldset variable of a ModelAdmin class as required so that the user cannot create or update a user instance if those fields are not selected in the form. How can I do that?

```
class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    error_message = UserCreationForm.error_messages.update({
        'duplicate_username': 'This username has already been taken.'
    })
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = AuthUserAdmin.fieldsets + (
            (None, {'fields': ('user_type', 'country')}),
    )
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
```

Here I want to make country and user_type as required in the admin panel. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer provided by @Lewis is correct it did not work for me.
The below solution worked for me.

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = AuthUserAdmin.fieldsets + (
            (None, {'fields': ('user_type', 'country')}),
    )
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['user_type'].required = True
        form.base_fields['country'].required = True
        return form
```